# SimpleCart not allowing thousand comma separator

Tags: javascript, regex, simplecart

I am using simplecart. Nice and simple, I have dealt with most of its flaws but this one is bothering me still.

a price is presented with , as a thousand separator, pretty standard stuff!

EG: $2,456.55

once its added to the cart its added as only 2 This must be the comma.

I think I have found the offending line:

```
_data.price = parseFloat(_data.price.replace(simpleCart.currency().decimal, ".").replace(/[^0-9\.]+/ig, ""));
```

What should I add to remove any found comma to the REGEX?

Comment: `replace(/[^0-9\.]+/ig, "")` is already removing comma or any other non digit/period.

Comment: What does `simpleCart.currency().decimal` return?

Comment: my bad, the issue is elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

to only remove `,`, this one is simpler

```
replace(/,/, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

issue not in simplecart. Its in a presentation script in PHP using floatval without first removing the commas.....